# Is it possible while after having had a South African general work permit, to still enter visa-free for tourism?

Tags: visas, south-africa, visa-free-entry, visa-runs, working-visas

Here is my situation. I am a Belgian national and I will be working in South Africa for 2 years on a 24 month general work permit. I will be starting in November 2016 and finishing by the end of October 2018. This means my general working permit will also expire in October 2018.

I know it's planning far ahead in time but I'd like to stay around for another 3 months or so more after having finished my two year contract to travel around the country and some neighbouring countries during summer till the end of January 2019.

If I'd leave South Africa before the end of October 2018 (while still on my 24 month work permit) and travel around Zimbabwe/Botswana/Nambia for a couple of weeks and come back to SA in let's say, mid December 2018 (after my work permit got expired), will I be granted a 90-day visa-free stay like most EU citizens travelling to South Africa?

Hope someone will be able to answer my question!

Thanks

Yannick

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, when exiting South Africa upon finishing your work, you should declare to the immigration authorities that you're finished with your work, so they can properly cancel your work permit.

After that, there should be no Problems whatsoever entering visa-free as a Tourist.

However, since South Africa has been changing some immigration regulations recently, you may wish to e-mail the immigration authorities regarding this.

One Person I know of is the Chief immigration officer at Cape Town Airport, Juanita Britz. She should be able to give an authoritative answer. Her address is Juanita.Britz@dha.gov.za

Another Person is the head of Cape Town Airport, Alex Kemp. alex.kemp@dha.gov.za

Comment: Yes, sorry, I am aware of the 90 day visa free period EU-citizens are allowed. That's what I meant but I wrote it mistakenly as '90 day tourist visa'. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Do you really want to post the immigration officer's direct email address?  Lots of people other than the OP are going to see this post, and likely send her inquiries that ought really to go through proper channels.

Comment: @NateEldredge It is available online, that's where I found it, though it was a lot of digging for me so I don't remember where I found it anymore

Comment: @NateEldredge It was here, but they now list one Alex Kamp instead, who isn't however an immigration officer, but the head of airport http://www.home-affairs.gov.za/index.php/contact-us/43-south-african-airports